inline кнопки node-telegram-bot-api
node-telegram-bot-api. Как сделать так, что бы кнопку мог нажать только 1 человек ( человек которого пинганули, у нас только @username), и
при этом человек который ввел команду, не мог использовать эту кнопку

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Если я правильно понял вопрос,.. то единственный способ — отдавать кнопку тому кого пинганули. Т.е. бот должен получить  @username и отправить кнопку конкретному пользователю.

Человек пишет команду в группе с пингом юзера, и отправляется сообщение с кнопкой, и надо сделать так что бы эту кнопку мог нажать ТОЛЬКО человек которого пинганули

@SWASTRIMS я вам и ответил как это сделать. Для того, чтобы эту кнопку мог нажать только "пингуемый", то и отправлять эту кнопку нужно только ему. Если вы отправите любой интерактивный элемент в общий чат, то он одинаково кликабелен будет доступен для всех. Вы конечно можете отфильтровать на стороне бота кто кликнул, но зачем вам этот гемор? +когда пишете в комментах, ставьте "обращение", начиная с @+никнейм. Тогда мне прилетит уведомление. Например @stylok.

@stylok отпрвлять куда? в личные сообщения?

@SWASTRIMS можно реализовать как угодно. Например как бы это сделал я? 1. пользователь  отправляет сообщение боту, допустим текстом: /ping @SWA ты жив?; 2. бот отрабатывает пересылку, и тебе в личку приходит: @stylok интересуется: "ты жив?" с кнопкой. 3. при необходимости или по желанию бот подчищает отправленное мной сообщение.

функционально можно добавить проверку на существование пользователя и уведомление если пользователь отписался от канала, а то мало ли.


@stylok , у меня чат бот и вот такое не подходит в случае когда кнопку может нажать только тот кто отправил команду

@SWASTRIMS "тот кто отправил команду"? Вы хотели сказать "тот кому отправили команду" (тот кого пинганули)? Некорректность вашего изначального вопроса оставляет ряд возможностей для домыслов. Во-первых, бот может быть как персональным, т.е. каждый юзер подписан на бота и ничего не знает от других подписчиках. Во-вторых, бот может быть  наблюдателем/участником/админом канала или группы. В-третьих, он может совмещать в себе оба функционала т.е. одновременно быть и частью группы и выполнять дополнительный функционал для тех, кто подписан на него. Выше я рассматривал именно третий вариант.
